# How to change git submodule tracking remote branch?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I add a submodule using following command

> git submodule add -b br1 [repo]

The .gitmodules file has entry branch=br1 . Now I want to switch the branch to br2. I can go into submodule folder and switch the branch but that does not update .gitmodules file.

How I can do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  If you think about it, if you change the branch which the submodule is tracking, then wouldn't that possibly throw off everyone else's code?  Submodules is one area of Git which is very tricky.  There might be a workaround to your problem.

Comment: I am working on a stable branch br1 and want to test on experimental br2. If I do not update .gitmodules files other users will not be able to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git uses .gitmodules for storing a link to your submodule project, but not a particular version of it. So when you switch branch of the submodule, git .gitmodules file is not changed.

Instead git updates commit number of your submodule version when you change the submodule. If you look at your upper module

```
git diff
```

you'll see something like

```
-Subproject commit 829b869657418fdac7964c3671ed9a378f09c032
+Subproject commit 829b869657418fdac7964c3671ed9a378f09c032-dirty
```

If you wish everybody uses new submodule branch, you have to commit & push that change (new submodule commit number) into your upper module repo.

Basically it works like a link to the particular submodule version.

Look here for details: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules#Starting-with-Submodules

Comment: I did not see the diff because I created a branch and that does not do anything other than pointer!

Comment: But still, this is about the commit.

If you want to update the commit *and* change the branch, is the correct workflow to edit the .gitmodules file directly?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. This is how I solved.

Because the main repo tracked a branch, not a specific commit, pulling changes in the submodule or switching branch makes no modification in the main repo.

Instead, edit the `.gitmodules` file.
There is a line

```
branch = br1
```

Replace it with the new branch (after at least a fetch in the submodule)

```
branch = br2
```

Then in a new commit, you can describe that br2 tracked from now on.

Then any other developer can update their clone with `git submodule update --remote` to pull you changes, and track `br2`.